# Extracting mean value per layer for raster with terra package in R

Tags: r, terra, global, mean

I have a stack of monthly temperature raster data and would like to calculate the global spatial mean per area using the `terra` package in R to obtain a monthly time series.

I tried `terra::app` and `terra::mean` but they both give me a raster with a temporal average per gridcell, not the spatial average. `terra::extract` might be another solution but I can't seem to get it to work, since I am interested in the global mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are after the function `terra::global`. Make sure to use na.rm=TRUE else wise, if there are NA' present the result will be NA. If the SpatRaster object is multi-layer, results will be returned for each layer.

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols=100, nrows=100)
  r[] <- runif(ncell(r))
    r[c(50,100,1000)] <- NA

global(r, "mean")
global(r, "mean", na.rm=TRUE)
```

If you need to return the specific value to use as a scalar a given band can be indexed. Otherwise the returned object is a data.frame and a function that is expecting a numeric value will fail.

```
class(global(r, "mean", na.rm=TRUE))
global(r, "mean", na.rm=TRUE)[,1]
```